# TSQL , Weekday output

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions

This function should accept date and output the day of the week. I tried the code before , but there was no result

```
alter procedure udfWeek(@days datetime)
AS
begin
declare @day nvarchar(max)= DATEPART(weekday, @days)
print @day

end
go 
select dbo.udfWeek('2011-11-11')
```

Comment: print statements do not create rows in the output stream. Rather, they are information messages. So, your stored procedure does not emit a rowset. Use a SELECT statement instead of PRINT, if you want to emit rows from a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want a **Scalar-Valued FUNCTION** and not a PROCEDURE

```
Create function dbo.udfWeek (@days datetime)
Returns int
Begin
    Return DATEPART(weekday, @days)
End
go 

select dbo.udfWeek('2011-11-11')
```